# Regex expression for removing hidden characters in Javascript

Tags: regex, jscript

My compiler is evaluating "15 000,00" == "15 000,00" to false in JScript. Can someone point me to the correct regex expression to remove any hidden characters affecting the comparison?

Comment: `replace('[^\w]', '')` ... it is not the right syntax but you can find out from it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Replace the space ' '(Unicode value:160) with space ' '(Unicode value:32) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try Trimming(removing white spaces at ends) the strings since even if your string contains white spaces at ends this will return false.

```
"15 000,00" == "15 000,00 "  => This will return you false.
```

But trimming as shown below will return you true.

```
"15 000,00" == "15 000,00 ".trim()
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but the hidden character seems to be the space in between 5 and 0 which is unaffected by trim.

Comment: Sorru S.S. but i am not able to reproduce your scenario at my end.

Comment: Hi @S.S. 
Please try following expression for both the parameters and let me know if it works 

("15 000,00 ").replace(/[^a-z0-9\s\w]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '')

Here replace(/[^a-z0-9\s\w]/gi, '') will remove all the special characters here like , (It will replace all the special characters with space).

Then replace(/[_\s]/g, '') this will remove all the empty spaces in  the string.